# Cannot refresh page in production when compiled with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am building an app using node.js + express.js + react.js and I'm using webpack to compile the client side code. The problem I am having is after my client side code is compiled with webpack and I run my app, I cannot refresh the page.

My code:

My webpack compiles my files into `/dist/index.html`, my app runs on port 3000, and all client side routes are prefixed with `/admin`.

```
 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('dist/index.html');
});
```

When I go to `localhost:3000` in the browser and click around the links, the app works fine. However, if I go to, as an example, the `about` page:

`localhost:3000/admin/about`

And I refresh, I get the error `Cannot GET /admin/about`.

I believe the reason is my express router only knows about the `/` route... so If I refresh directly onto a route like `/admin/about`, express doesn't know what to render so my solution was to include a "catch all" route:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('dist/index.html');
});
```

However, this keeps giving me the `Error: Failed to lookup view &quot;dist/index.html&quot;` error.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After research, I found the solution isn't `res.render` but `res.sendFile`:

`res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/index.html'));`